# Why do I get this error on this specific query when it works with similar ones?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a job on my SQL server 2017 that consists of only 2 steps, being that the seond step is just to send an email. The code I have is this:

```
    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = 'SQL Server - 2017',  
    @recipients = 'filipeferreira@mass.pt',  
    @query = 'select * from bo
where nmdos like "%preço%"
and datafinal = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))' ,  
    @subject = 'Encerramento Dossier',  
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Can't find the mistake, I get test emails from email server, any thoughts on this?

THE ERROR I GET IS:

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

Is it possible to create a simple job, with just the select, and an alert if it returns something? That would work to, but i´m not getting it

Comment: What is "this error" ?

Comment: Should be 2 single quotes instead of double quotation for escaping after `where nmdos like` in your query

Comment: "I get this error" will not help us help you.  What error???  How do you expect us to help you if the only information we have is "this error"???

Comment: ups, sorry mates, I was so bummed with the error i gorfot to post it. edited the original post!

Comment: There are a few reasons for this error. You should google it and try them all out first. In my case it appearS to be because the SQL Server service account was not set to a domain account... though I'm yet to check. After you have googled you should try a simple call without a query and see if that works